# Most current redhat-supported ruby version for RHEL 5.3?

Tags: ruby, linux, redhat

So I'm trying to get some leg work out of the way for our shop's SA in order to request an upgrade to our currently installed ruby on several Redhat Enterprise Linux production servers.

There are some complicating factors though:

- The upgrade has to be in rpm form
- The rpm has to be from a redhat repo

I have searched the redhat docs and have found the needed information for RHEL 6, but not 5. I spent a significant amount of time googling, but most of the solutions involved either pulling from a non-redhat site, or compiling from source -- neither of which our SA will go for. I searched stackoverflow, and did not find this specific question being asked, or addressed in other answers for similar questions.

Some Relevant info from one of the servers (they're all identical):

```
foo@bar:~ $ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga)

foo@bar:~ $ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.5 (2006-08-25) [x86_64-linux]
```

Does anyone have specific links to official redhat documentation and repo for the most recent version of supported ruby for RHEL 5.3?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release manifest displays the software included with 5.3, you can find it here:
[Red Hat Enterprise 5.3 - Release Manifest](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.3/pdf/Release_Manifest.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply!

Sorry for my ignorance, but on page 127 there is the line:

`ruby-1.8.5-5.el5 - ruby-1.8.5-5.el5_2.6`

Is this to say that v1.8.5 is the only supported version for RHEL 5.3?

Thanks again.

Comment: No, but yes.  The default repo only contains what red hat has tested with 5.3 and is believed to be the most stable versions. Additional repositories can be enabled and could contain either updates (1.8.7) or newer verisons of packages.  RHEL is built to be a stable system and usually ships/repos contains the last stable version they tested with.  It is left to the user/sys admin to upgrade their version or find a repo that contains an updated version, but RHEL does not suggest this, since it could potentially become, in their eyes, an unstable system.